# What does this mean **&a in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

What is different between two fucntions bellow?

```
void init1(int **&a, int n)
{
    a = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = new int [n];
}
```

and

```
void init1(int **a, int n)
{
    a = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        a[i] = new int [n];
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that in the `int **&a` version, `a` has been passed by reference. If you change the value of the pointer itself (that is to say, write code like `a = a+5;`) the value of `a` will be modified in the original calling function.

Answer (score 0):

The first function passes the double pointer `a` by reference and the second function just passes the double pointer `a` as an argument.

In the first function, any modification done to `a` will persist after the function has exited unlike in the second where any modification to `a` will not persist.